# remove immediate duplicate steps from a sequence and keep one instance

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a following sequence of paths in bigquery

other>>other>>other>>other>>PDP Base>>PDP Base>>Tariff>>other>>other>>other>>other>>other>>other>>other>>other>>other>>other>>other>>other

I want to remove immediate duplicates to change the string to something like
other>>pdp base>>tariff>>other

Comment: What is a path in BigQuery?  I am familiar with lots of things like projects, datasets, tables, views, types, CTEs, and so on.  I don't know what a "path" is.

Answer (score 2):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  (SELECT STRING_AGG(step, '>>' ORDER BY pos) FROM 
    (SELECT 
      step, pos, IFNULL(step = LAG(step) OVER(ORDER BY pos), FALSE) dup
     FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(path, '>>')) step WITH OFFSET pos
    ) 
    WHERE NOT dup
  ) cleaned_path
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

If to apply to sample data from your question as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'other>>other>>other>>other>>PDP Base>>PDP Base>>Tariff>>other>>other>>other>>other>>other>>other>>other>>other>>other>>other>>other>>other' path
)
SELECT 
  (SELECT STRING_AGG(step, '>>' ORDER BY pos) FROM 
    (SELECT 
      step, pos, IFNULL(step = LAG(step) OVER(ORDER BY pos), FALSE) dup
     FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(path, '>>')) step WITH OFFSET pos
    ) 
    WHERE NOT dup
  ) cleaned_path
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

result is

```
Row cleaned_path     
1   other>>PDP Base>>Tariff>>other
```

Comment: Thanks very much Mikhail. This is really useful.